# WebKit get elements URL? iOS8

Tags: html, ios, ios8, wkwebview

I'm making an app that uses a WKWebView and I need to be able to get the URL of any HTML element on the page. For example, say the user goes to google images and long-presses on an image, I need to be able to find the full URL to that image.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour could be accomplished via these 4 steps:

1) Add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your `WKWebView` instance and don't forget to allow your recognizer to recognize simultaneously with own `WKWebView` gesture recognizer:

```
SEL selector = @selector(handleLongPressGestureRecognizer:);
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gestuRecognizer =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                        action:selector];
gestuRecognizer.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:gestuRecognizer];

<...>

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
        (UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return YES;
}
```

2) Create JavaScript file(tools.js) roughly like that:

```
function imageSourceFromPoint(x, y) {
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  if (element.tagName == 'IMG' && element.src) {
    return element.src;
  }
  return null;
}
```

3) Load that tools.js into your web page. This could be done straight in `handleLongPressGestureRecognizer` method for example:

```
- (void)handleLongPressGestureRecognizer:
    (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [self loadJavaScriptFileIfNeededWithCompletion:^{
      <...>
    }];
  }
}

- (void)loadJavaScriptFileIfNeededWithCompletion:(void(^)())completion {
  <...>
  [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:[self toolsJavaScriptFile]
                 completionHandler:^(id result, NSError* error) {
                   completion();
                 }];
  <...>
}

- (NSString*)toolsJavaScriptFile {
  NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tools"
                                                   ofType:@"js"];
  return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                      error:nil];
}
```

4) Execute `imageSourceFromPoint` JavaScript function from Objective-C (or Swift) with location of long press gesture:

```
- (void)handleLongPressGestureRecognizer:
    (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    <...>
    [self loadJavaScriptFileIfNeededWithCompletion:^{
      CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.webView];
      [self imageSourceFromPoint:touchPoint completion:^(NSString* source) {
        <...>
      }];
    }];
    <...>
}

- (void)imageSourceFromPoint:(CGPoint)point
                  completion:(void(^)(NSString*))completion {
  NSString* jsCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:
      @"imageSourceFromPoint(%g, %g)", point.x, point.y];
  [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:jsCode
                 completionHandler:^(id result, NSError* error) {
                   <...>
                   NSString* resultString = (NSString*)result;
                   completion(resultString);
                 }];
}
```

Note that bunch of error checks were omitted, full project sample you can find here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/930742/so/GetHTMLElement.zip

It looks like this:

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is such an awesome response! Thanks!